# Using keyof typeof for object state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, types

What should be the type for key? if i add (key: string) i get an error that "string" cant be used to index type " active1: boolean, active2"

```
const [actives, setActives] = React.useState({
  active1: false,
  active2: false,
});

const toggle = (key) => setActives((actives) => ({ ...actives, [key]: !actives[key] }));
    
return (
  <View>
    <Button onPress={() => toggle('active1')} active={actives.active1} />
    <Button onPress={() => toggle('active2')} active={actives.active2} />
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Are you looking for `keyof`? That would be easier to use if you extracted an explicit type, otherwise you also have to use `typeof` to get the inferred type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keyof typeof active` or `keyof T` where `T` is a type you defined for that object state.

```
function Comp () {
    const [actives, setActives] = React.useState({
    active1: false,
    active2: false,
    });

    const toggle = (key: keyof typeof actives) => setActives((actives) => ({ ...actives, [key]: !actives[key] }));
        
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => toggle('active1')} disabled={!actives.active1} />
            <button onClick={() => toggle('active2')} disabled={!actives.active2} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFA0ECuAdvsBE3AMIlhwAUASjgBvGnHFxc7VPADaeGMABuWVABo4qLDACCrFagC6cALyYqMAHQMtAZRjIYWPqIkp9WAIwAuOAWQANlpqYhIKylgATL7+QVghbgC+AgDcdG5STDJwMBAA5nkBWKb8ANZYAJ6+5RUQBDkVYFh17ooGQiYAfJraem2qfHzh7abdLnCWk8OqGrI1hr4AhNOoc5XGyamhbuLbcJQwDFAcfHtuADwAJsqdZzvi5wBGDDC5HOycAcC4pSbCgqMcvlCs4yNNPGQBIk4NdUMhHkVLn9lh5UJZwdCAPS3e73J4vN5wD5fH5-AFdIEFIp8MEeSKQ6Gw+GI5ErdF0rE43HnTHXJRc8RbRI0IA)